# view seems cut off in object mode

Tags: camera

So when I'm in render preview I can see everything but everything cut off in object mode

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You accidently pressed ALT + B, which is used to set the view clipping border. Just press that again and your view will be normal again.

Further info: [Blender Wiki Article about View Clipping Border](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/3dview/navigate/clip.html)